# popup windows in not opened in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, confirm, popupwindow

I am using codeigniter and in one of the views I have the following function triggered when the employee code does not exist in the database(using jquery ajax - works fine). the confirm popup displayes when the entered code is not valid but when the result of confrim is true, the following code does not fire the popup window!

```
function popup(){
        if(confirm("Employee_code not available! \nSave the code as new employee?")){
            //var new_emp_window = "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/it_inventory/new_employee'; ?>";
            widnow.open('www.google.com', 'width=500, height=500');
        }else{
            alert("ohh!");
            $('#employee_code').val('').focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all change `www.google.com` to http://www.google.com. As the browser handles URLs without protocol prefix as relative paths.
2. Check that popup blocker is not active on your browser.

Answer (score 2):

it should be **window** not **widnow**, change:

```
widnow.open
```

to

```
window.open
```

try:

```
window.open("www.google.com", "_blank", "width=500,height=500");
```

See: [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open)

Comment: Oh my god, my bad! but that is only a typo in my typing..! it is not really the case!